Hydration class mismatch on <div class=​"_root_6wgg2_1 _view__default_6wgg2_24">​…​</div>
I am using Nuxt 3 SSR. I have a store alert that is responsible for all the popup notifications on the page. When I submit a request, I ask store to pass an error message and display the alert. But in the end, the message is not displayed and an error is displayed in the console:
Hydration class mismatch on <div class=​"_root_6wgg2_1 _view__default_6wgg2_24">​…​​flex

rendered on server: class="_root_6wgg2_1 _view__default_6wgg2_24"
expected on client: class="_root_6wgg2_1 _view__danger_6wgg2_28 _show_6wgg2_19"
Note: this mismatch is check-only. The DOM will not be rectified in production due to performance overhead.
You should fix the source of the mismatch.

That's where I make the request to set the alert.
      const { data, status }: any = await useAsyncData('api', () => $api('/auth/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          code: route.query.code,
          state: route.query.state,
        },
      }));
      if (status.value === 'success') {
...
      }
      else {
        const alert = useAlertStore();
        alert.showAlert({
          message: 'Authorization error!',
          view: 'danger',
        });
      }

Here's how I install alert in the store:
  const showAlert = (newAlertData: AlertData) => {
    alertData.value = { ...newAlertData };

    alertData.value.isShow = true;
  };

I've read about what could be causing this, tried to change the links somehow, but nothing helped. Please help.

Can start here but overall, there is probably a difference between what your server fetches and what your client-side does. A mismatch is a difference between both. Feel free to goggle on/off the JS to narrow it down.
